# Qemu recursive macro wrong output

Tags: assembly, arm, qemu

Can any one explain what is wrong with my code, Iam using `qemu` with packages `arm-linux-gnueabi` and `gnueabi-gcc` to run and test `assembly` program.

My program is creating `macro` called `enum` that place a sequence of numbers into memory, but when am running the program it does not show the numbers, it only print 0, instead of all sequence numbers ? any help

```
.data      
   rez: .asciz "the number is %d\n"  
   
.macro  enum from=0, into=5
.long   \from
.if    \into-\from
enum    "(\from+1)",\into
.endif
.endm

.global main
.extern printf
.func main

main:
    enum 0,6
    bx lr
```

Comment: Where is the printing? Also you have a typo `from3` ... it does not even assemble. Make sure you show the code you actually use.

Comment: @Jester My mistake in macro, I dont know to add print ? any help please?

Comment: @Frant I just updated the macro cuz there is an error in from3, I do not know where to add printf in my code any help please?

Comment: @Frant I did not have any error in assembling, could you please now check ? and help me where to add printf function to print numbers ?

Comment: @Jester any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at the generated code, since your macro may not exactly do what you are expecting, including calling `printf`.

`startup-aarch32.s`:

```
                .title startup-aarch32.s
                .arch armv7-a
                .text
                .section .text.startup,"ax"
                .globl Reset_Handler

                .macro  enum from=0, into=5
                .long   \from
                .if    \into-\from
                 enum    "(\from+1)",\into
                .endif
                .endm

Reset_Handler:
                ldr r0, =__StackTop
                mov sp, r0
                bl main
wait:           wfe
                b wait
main:
               enum 0,6
               bx lr
.data
rez:           .asciz "the number is %d\n"
               .end

/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -o startup3-aarch2.o startup-aarch32.s
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d startup3-aarch2.o

startup3-aarch2.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <Reset_Handler>:
   0:   e59f002c        ldr     r0, [pc, #44]   ; 34 <main+0x20>
   4:   e1a0d000        mov     sp, r0
   8:   eb000001        bl      14 <main>

0000000c <wait>:
   c:   e320f002        wfe
  10:   eafffffd        b       c <wait>

00000014 <main>:
  14:   00000000        .word   0x00000000
  18:   00000001        .word   0x00000001
  1c:   00000002        .word   0x00000002
  20:   00000003        .word   0x00000003
  24:   00000004        .word   0x00000004
  28:   00000005        .word   0x00000005
  2c:   00000006        .word   0x00000006
  30:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
  34:   00000000        .word   0x00000000
```

As you can see, the macro is mixing data and instructions, which is likely preventing you to get the result you were expecting by causing an invalid instruction  fault.

You probably need to rework it a bit, and IMHO, this is always a good thing than to look at the code that was generated.

Comment: the macro generate multiple .long values, .long 0 .long 1 .long 2 until last element 6, the rez is only one %d instead of long, so should I use multiple %f ? and how to fix it please, the macro is look ok, but the other parts is I dont know hwo to fix ?!!

Comment: The question I attempted to answer to was:  'what is wrong in my code', and I thing I provided a valid answer. This being said, if this is part of an assignment, the best think for you is to find the solution by yourself, so that you may learn/progress. This forum is simply not a place for getting his homework done by others. But you can ask further questions in the case the subsequent versions of your code may still not work.

Comment: I try to understand the macros and how they work, so I created my own macro, I just want your help to print the long numbers in macro ? any help please? I really appreciate

Comment: I wish if you could answer me 1 quest, the .long first number in enum, I want to print it how? phow do I load it to memory and printf ?

Comment: Tons of examples for that, but ... first you need to move it out of `main` and give it a separate label, say `array:`. You should also switch back to `.text` for `main` as it should not go into `.data`. Then you just need invoke `printf`, e.g. `ldr r0, =rez; ldr r1, =array; ldr r1, [r1]; bl printf; b exit`. (Note I changed to `exit` to avoid saving `lr`.)